# meson incorrect handling cuda nvcc flags

Tags: cuda, nvcc, meson-build

I have to a build cuda library  with meson and the flags I need to provide are:

```
NVCCFLAGS = -ccbin g++ --threads 0 -std=c++17 -c -arch=sm_86 -gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61  -m64
```

the meson.build is

```
# Builds lib-gpu as a dependency called "lib_gpu_dep".
add_languages('cuda')

subdir('src')

project_source_files = [
    source_files_src,
    ]
    
build_args_common = [
              '-ccbin', 
              'g++',
              '-c',
              '-arch=sm_86',
              '-gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61',
              '-m64',
              ]    
              
if (get_option('unit_test'))
build_args = [build_args_common,
              '-g',
              '-G',
              '-DDEBUG=1'
              ]
else
build_args = [
              build_args_common,
              '-src-in-ptx',
              ' -keep',
               # '--keep-dir=build/$(BUILD_TYPE)',
              ' --use_fast_math',
              ' -lineinfo'
              ]
endif

 

cuda_src_dir = '/usr/local/cuda'
inc_dir_cuda = include_directories(cuda_src_dir  + '/include')
lib_gpu_incdir = include_directories('inc', is_system : true)

lib_gpu_name = 'lib_gpu'

lib_gpu = static_library(
  lib_gpu_name,
  project_source_files,
  cuda_args : build_args,
  gnu_symbol_visibility : 'default',
  include_directories : [lib_gpu_incdir, inc_dir_cuda])


lib_gpu_dep = declare_dependency(
  include_directories : lib_gpu_incdir,
  link_with : lib_gpu
)
```

in the generated ninja file I have

```
ARGS = -Ilib-gpu/liblib_gpu.a.p -Xcompiler=-Wall,-Winvalid-pch,-Wnon-virtual-dtor,-Wextra,-Wpedantic -Xcompiler=-fPIC -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/usr/local/cuda/include -isystem=../lib-gpu/inc -ccbin g++ -c -arch=sm_86 '-gencode$ arch=compute_61,code=sm_61' -m64 -Wno-pedantic -g -G -DDEBUG=1 -I../lib-gpu -Ilib-gpu -Ilib-gpu/liblib_gpu.a.p
```

but the flags `'-gencode$ arch=compute_61,code=sm_61'`  is not correct

and in order to compile I need to modify it with a script to

-gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61

is there a way to solve this problem?
the version used is

```
meson --version
0.59.1
```

Comment: what happens if you just delete these 2 lines: `'-gencode',
              ' arch=compute_61,code=sm_61',` ?

Comment: Looks like you are compiling for sm_61 and not sm_86

Comment: yes but this is not the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead to use

```
'-gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61',
```

is it possible to write

```
'-gencode=arch=compute_61,code=sm_61',
```

in this case the flag generated by meson is correct.